# Overlapping score for each feature in the merged layer after spatial joins

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, area, overlapping-features

I've clicked on the <kbd>Join attributes by location</kbd> button and can join two layers. But in the merged layer, how do I find out percentage of overlap/intersect calculated for each feature?

[image]

For example, in the result, I'd like to know the `"overlaps"` score for each feature in the merged layer.

Comment: Have you seen this thread [Calculating percentage of overlap of two layers in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339929/calculating-percentage-of-overlap-of-two-layers-in-qgis-3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the field calculator.
Using the excellent guide [here](https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/12/summary-aggregation-qgis/) and some changes I got the percent of intersecting area,
which will be equivalent to the overlapping area.
I did the calculation for the orange `polygon a` layer.

[image]

The expression I used was:

```
array_first(
    aggregate(
     layer:= 'polygon b',
     aggregate:='array_agg',
     expression:=area(intersection($geometry, geometry(@parent)))/area(geometry(@parent)),
     filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
     )
 )
```

What it does is collect all the intersecting geometries from the other layer, and then divides the intersecting area from the area of `polygon a` (the `@parent` layer).
I had to wrap it all up in `array_first` since the output of `aggregate` is an array, in this case of length 1, so first is just as good as last.

These are the results of the calculation.
shown with a label of

```
'percent overlap: '+  to_string(  round( "precent_overlap"*100,2) )+'%'
```

[image]