# How to make a projection of a linear layer on an another layer

Tags: qgis, geometry, geoprocessing

I'd like to know how to make a projection of a complex linear layer on an another layer, overlapping their geometries perfectly and considering the extremities of lyr_1; using geoprocessing of QGIS. For example, i'd like to project the layer 1 on the layer 2:

input:
[image]

output:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: See this solution here: works the same for lines: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/384194/88814

Comment: Check this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361398/projecting-polygons-into-polyline/361408#361408

Comment: I'm using this solution but the points created with the "virtual layer" are on the lyr_2 on twice sides; in the line in front of it and on the left line. Shouldn't create only on the nearest side? Thx!